# Wlan roaming mesh assumptions and authorization to fake AP

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11, wireless-roaming

[image: topology in image]

I have some questions and assumptions and I want to ask about them:
Based on topology in my picture: Assuming situation 1:
APs are configured just as APs with WPA3 Personal, they don't know about each other anything.

Windows 10 client comes to the left AP for the first time, it signs in to the network WlanGuestNetwork for the first time.

Will client moves from coverage of the left AP to the coverage of the right AP - it will not connect to WlanGuestNetwork of the right AP, because of different BSSID? What if attacker makes a similar to the left AP, that will also copy BSSID of the Left AP, will client try to auto reconnect to fake AP or there is some sort of protection going on? If it will try to connect, will there password be exposed, or is there some fancy hashing system that will prevent it?

Situation 2.
If we want client to seamlessly roam between those 2 APs the only wired solution is to implement MESH network with some manufacturer provided standard, this means that we need controller, for enterprise devices there will be hardware controller and for consumer devices one AP will act as a controller?

Now WDS is wireless only interconnection, because it needs support from AP interconnecting protocol, and 802.11 has some 4 mac address support and so on, while MESH can have both wired and wireless backbone, but logic behind AP interconnection in both case fundamentally different? Is there MESH APs, that have wired/wireless backbone failover, e.q. if you cut the cable, stations will still be connected wirelessly?

With mesh, roaming switching quality is entirely on the client, only some APs have support to drop clients with low signal, forcing them to sihti and latest 6E standard has something to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will client moves from coverage of the left AP to the coverage of the right AP - it will not connect to WlanGuestNetwork of the right AP, because of different BSSID?

It will, as long as the ESSID is the same. (BSSIDs are *meant* to be unique; the ESSID or "network name" is what sets the roaming boundary.) However, at least Windows will insist that the security mode needs to be the same as well.

> What if attacker makes a similar to the left AP, that will also copy BSSID of the Left AP, will client try to auto reconnect to fake AP or there is some sort of protection going on? If it will try to connect, will there password be exposed, or is there some fancy hashing system that will prevent it?

The WPA-Personal handshake never exposes the actual password. WPA/WPA2 use a challenge-response mechanism to derive the connection keys without sending the password over the air at all.

(It is possible to bruteforce the password given a captured WPA or WPA2 handshake, but if an attacker is in a position to set up an AP, they can just as well capture real handshakes off the air. With WPA3 it's supposed to be harder.)

> Situation 2. If we want client to seamlessly roam between those 2 APs the only wired solution is to implement MESH network with some manufacturer provided standard, this means that we need controller, for enterprise devices there will be hardware controller and for consumer devices one AP will act as a controller?

No, it does not mean that. Clients will seamlessly roam between any APs that share the same ESSID (and security settings).

"Mesh network" almost always means a network of APs that use *wireless* uplinks, with 802.11s or similar. None of that is necessary if the APs already have a wired connection.

A controller may make the roaming process *more* seamless by having the APs exchange client keys over Ethernet, but it's all optional.

> Is there MESH APs, that have wired/wireless backbone failover, e.q. if you cut the cable, stations will still be connected wirelessly?

I've seen such products exist (but personally, IMO, it's a misfeature – it just delays the repair because "eh, it works anyway"). Some APs just stop advertising the SSID if they lose connection, forcing clients to roam to another AP.